# How to do distinct in inner join in oracle 11.g?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my code.

```
insert into tblteam 
SELECT  t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t3.SUBJECTEND, t1.teamseq
FROM tblteam t1
INNER JOIN TBLCLASS t2 ON t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
INNER JOIN TBLOPENCOURSE T ON T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
INNER JOIN TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 ON T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
INNER JOIN TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 ON T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
INNER JOIN TBLSUBJECT T5 ON T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ
where  (t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME) in (
    SELECT DISTINCT t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
    FROM tblteam t1
             INNER JOIN TBLCLASS t2 ON t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
             INNER JOIN TBLOPENCOURSE T ON T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
             INNER JOIN TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 ON T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
             INNER JOIN TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 ON T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
             INNER JOIN TBLSUBJECT T5 ON T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ
);
```

and if I execute this code

```
select t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ;
```

Here are the results:

```
50,1
50,1
50,1
50,1
50,1
50,1
50,2
50,2
50,2
...
49,3
49,3
49,4
49,4
49,4
49,4
49,4
49,4
49,5
49,5
49,5
49,5
49,5
49,5
```

To see the results, duplicate values ​​come out over and over again.

I want result as like

```
50,1
50,2
...
49,2
49,3
49,4
49,5
```

I want to **distinct these duplicate result** values ​​in an `inner join`, but I'm curious how it is possible.

I tried to solve the problem like this.

```
select t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
from tblteam t1
          inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
          inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
          inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
          inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
          inner join(
              select distinct subjectseq, teamname from TBLSUBJECT, tblteam) t5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ;
```

However, the result is 750 rows, which is much higher than the previous 150 rows, and the number of duplicates has increased.

I was wondering if there is any solution to solve this.

**Of course I know it's okay to use distinct in select. But what I want is to use distinct in join statement because I can't use `=` in where statement.**

best regards

-----**append**------

here is all data

```
teamseq, t1.classseq, teamname, t2.classseq, studentseq, t2.opencourseseq, t.opencourseseq, coursestate, opensubjectregister, studentregister, coursestart, courseend, courseseq, classroomseq, opensubjectseq, subjectstart, subjectend, t3.availablesubjectseq, t3.opencourseseq, t4.availablesubjectseq, teahcerseq, t4.subjectseq, t5.subjectseq, subjectname, period, bookseq
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
```

Comment: I just saw this answer posted either by another user or you some time ago.  You may use a `DISTINCT SELECT` here.

Comment: *"Of course I know it's okay to use distinct in select. But what I want is to use distinct in join statement because I can't use = in where statement."* Why does it matter how you construct the WHERE clause? What do you mean by "distinct in inner join"? Perhaps a simple example with test data would help.

Comment: Just to check, are your JOIN as restrictive as possible? That could be as starting point to reduce the duplicates